# Can I implement a ListView adapter for an iterator?

Tags: android, listview, android-adapter

I have some kind of an iterator as an input for my module. It supports next(), prev(), hasNext(), hasPrev() and current() methods. It can contain a lot of items (actually, they are dynamically loaded from DB while iterating). It doesn't support count() or size() methods; I can't count them by iterating.

Design problems, I know :(

I have no access to that part of the system.

Can I implement an adapter for ListView without any information about count of items?

sorry for half-googled translate :(

Comment: Iterator doesn't move backwards, so you have to store results in a list, or make scrolling backwards an illegal operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could return results by batches and add them to an ArrayList as they are coming. When the user scrolls to the end of the list, you load the next batch.